# Unable to retrieve the location coordinates on clicking a checkbox in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, location, criteria

Here is the code i wrote to retrieve location coordiantes:

```
final EditField ed3=new EditField("Lat is ","");
    add(ed3);
    final EditField ed4=new EditField("Lon is ","");
    add(ed4);
CheckboxField cbf=new CheckboxField("test it",false);
     add(cbf);
     cbf.setChangeListener(new  FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            BlackBerryCriteria bc=new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_CELLSITE);
            LocationProvider lp3 = LocationProvider.getInstance(bc);
            Location loc = null;
            loc = lp3.getLocation(-1);
            if(loc != null)
            {
                QualifiedCoordinates qc=loc.getQualifiedCoordinates();
                double lat=qc.getLatitude();
                double lon=qc.getLongitude();
                ed3.setText(lat+"");
                ed4.setText(""+lon);
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });

}
```

But i am unable to retrieve the coordinates. Both the edit fields are left empty. What is the problem here? Please help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are making a blocking call (getLocation(-1)) on the event thread (servicing the field changed event).

This is very bad practice on BlackBerry platforms.

The other issue could be whether or not your service provider supports CELLSITE mode.

Comment: Okay then tell me the good practice. There is no problem with the service provider. Because i already tested by retrieving the location without clicking the checkbox (Updates the editfields automatically for every 30 seconds)

Comment: Any blocking or long running processes need to be run on a separate thread. This is covered in the coding style guides provided by RIM on their web pages set up to help developers get started with the BlackBerry platform.

Comment: In fact, getLocation should be throwing an exception when called from the event thread. You should run it on a separate thread, like @Richard Mentioned, and have that thread update the field.

Comment: Great thank you so much. It worked by using a separate thread